Django models cannot be queried due to missing id field?
I currently am working on a django project for a discord bot. the issue that I am trying to resolve is that I cannot seem to query the data for one of my models.
A piece of information that has been unclear to me that I am sure caused this issue was a series of migration issues I had trying to update my Character model with new relationships to the InventoryInstance model in a seperate app.
when I boot up a django shell_plus session - I get this error when trying to query the Character Model:
located in inventory.models
In [1]: Character.objects.all()
Out[1]: OperationalError: no such column: oblivionalchemy_character.inventory_instance_id

Here is my Character and InventoryInstance models:
located at oblivionalchemy.models
class InventoryInstance(models.Model):
    character_name = models.ForeignKey('oblivionalchemy.Character', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="character")
    items = models.JSONField(default=dict)


class Character(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('discordbot.DiscordUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="characters")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)  
    strength = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    endurance = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    agility = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    speed = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    willpower = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    intelligence = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    personality = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    luck = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    alchemy = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    survival = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    blade = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    marksman = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    inventory_instance = models.OneToOneField('inventory.InventoryInstance', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="character", null=True, blank=True)

I cannot seem to figure out a way to even interact with this data to recreate records after creating "upstream" dependencies on another model. Ideally I want the workflow to go
DiscordUser model record created
Character model record created
InventoryInstance model record created.
And I already had existing Character records before I created the DiscordUser model. But Im not sure I understand how to query this data and "catch it all up" after I've made changes to the model. Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?
Here is the initial migration files for each app:
oblivionalchemy
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('discordbot', '0001_initial'),
        ('inventory', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Character',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
                ('strength', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
                ('endurance', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
                ('agility', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
                ('speed', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
                ('willpower', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
                ('intelligence', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
                ('personality', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
                ('luck', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
                ('alchemy', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
                ('survival', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
                ('blade', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
                ('marksman', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
                ('inventory_instance', models.OneToOneField(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='character', to='inventory.inventoryinstance')),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='characters', to='discordbot.user')),
            ],
        ),
    ]

discordbot
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('discord_id', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, unique=True)),
            ],
        ),
    ]

inventory
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='InventoryInstance',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('items', models.JSONField(default=dict)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='InventoryItem',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
                ('weight', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('hitpoints', models.IntegerField(default=100)),
                ('is_default', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('effects', models.JSONField(default=inventory.models.default_effects_for_item)),
            ],
        ),
    ]


Have you not run makemigrations and migrate? "series of migration issues I had" and what did you do to resolve those (Thats important debugging information)? Is there no migration that is adding a OneToOneField to the Character model?

@AbdulAzizBarkat It looks like the initial migration file added the OneToOneField to Character and a ForeignKey to the InventoryInstance

I have discovered the issue, I was attempting to connect OneToOneField relations with ForeignKey fields in the "downstream" model and that was causing me some issues, I have corrected the error by simply placing OneToOneField relations between each of the models that require that functionality.
